# How to connect wire to a male JST connector?

Tags: connector, wire, cables

I have an EL panel with wire I want to connect to my Arduino shield (Escudo Dos), but the shield has a male JST (PH) connector, so there are protruding elements from both sides. What component do I need to connect the two? Do I just need the corresponding female version of the JST? Will the wire just stick into that or does it need to be secured in some way?

Answer (score 0):

The female JST connector comprises a plastic shell into which individual metal contacts are inserted. The contacts get crimped onto the wires prior to insertion, and this requires a special crimping tool.

If you only need a small quantity, distributors such as Digi-Key will crimp the contacts onto wires for you for a very reasonable fee. However, you say that your panel already has wires, so that might not be possible. You could order new wires with contacts on one end that could either be spliced to the existing wires, or used to replace them altogether.

Comment: I hate doing it but you can solder the contacts to the wires... but as these are spring type contacts it may reduce their pressure on the mating pin due to annealing of the metal by the heat of soldering. To get out of trouble once could be ok...just not in production or where there is a lot of vibrations...Also if the solder gets to the wrong places it may stop the pin going in the connector correctly.